# is Google V8 an environment in whish our code runs, so we can call it an execution context right?

Tags: javascript, web, development-environment, jdeveloper, executioncontext

please i'm struggling a lot these days to understand how the javascript works behind the scenes so it is Google V8 an environment in whish our code runs, so we can call it an execution context right?

Comment: No.  "Execution context" usually refers to the environment for a specific piece of code -- its call stack, scope, etc -- not to the javascript engine in its entirety.  By analogy, if your code were a car, its "execution context" would be the other cars and roads and pedestrians in its immediate surrounding area; not the entire highway system.

Comment: (Minor correction to the above, I was a bit sloppy with my terminology:  the call stack is a set of execution contexts, not part of a given context.  See [here](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-1-execution-contexts/) for way too much detail.)